# Why is my item Image in custom RecyclerView changing while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

My app works fine, except that i saw some items changing images while scrolling, somehow i know that's a recycling problem, but i dont know how to solve it. I tried some code modifications in my adapter, because I think its from there, but i didn't succeed.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter_VersionR.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //get current product of the list
    currentProduit = productList.get(position);

    try {
        getImgUrl = currentProduit.getUrlImageList_thumb().get(0);  
        Picasso.with(context).load(getImgUrl).fit().into(myImageView);
        Log.i("INFO", "Image loaded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        Log.e("ERROR", "No image or image error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the download image, I'm using Picasso, thanks for the help !

EDIT : FULL ADAPTER

```
private Product currentProduit;
private ImageView myImageView;
private Context context;
private List<Product> productList;
private String getAgencyName, getImgUrl;
private List<String> getUrlList_Thumb;
private List<String> getUrlList_Full;
private ImageButton favorite_img_btn;
private boolean star_isClicked;


public CustomAdapter_VersionR(Context ctx, List<Product> products) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.productList = products;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title, descrip, price, agency, country, city, type, nbRoom;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        //references to layout
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_product);
        descrip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descrip_product);
        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_product);
        myImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_product);
        agency = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agency_product);
        country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country_product);
        city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_product);
        type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type_product);
        nbRoom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nbRoom_product);
    }
}


@Override
public CustomAdapter_VersionR.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, parent, false);
    Log.i("INFO", "Creation ok");

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter_VersionR.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //get current product of the list
    currentProduit = productList.get(position);

    try {
        getImgUrl = currentProduit.getUrlImageList_thumb().get(0); 
        Picasso.with(context).load(getImgUrl).fit().into(myImageView);
        Log.i("INFO", "Image loaded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        Log.e("ERROR", "No image or image error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.agency.setText(currentProduit.getNomAgence();
    holder.descrip.setText(currentProduit.getDescription());
    holder.title.setText(currentProduit.getTitre());
    holder.price.setText(currentProduit.getPrix());
    holder.nbRoom.setText(currentProduit.getNbPieces());
    holder.country.setText(currentProduit.getPays());
    holder.city.setText(currentProduit.getVille());
    holder.type.setText(currentProduit.getType_produit());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}
```

EDIT: After some researches, there's something in my onBindViewHolder to add, but the placeholder doesn't work, I might be doing soemthing wrong with it..

Comment: Post full code for adapter. It seems like you are not using ViewHolder.

Comment: @drulabs , posted full code :)

Answer (score 11):

Override these 2 methods in your recyclerview adapter. This solves your problem.

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. I don't know why, but this worked for me. Is there any explanation?

Comment: Are you sure..that items still will be recycled or all the time new item will be created?

Comment: And this may cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 1):

It's because recycled view has previous item's information.
You have to provide placeholder image to myImageView.

Consider setting placeholder image like below:

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
try {
    // current try block
} catch {
    // current catch block
}
```

or providing placeholder image via Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(getImgUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .fit()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Where do I put the picasso placeholder ? In my try block ? or just before @crowjdh

Comment: I recommend before try block(former code block) because there's chance of failing to set placeholder image if something goes wrong in try block. Also, I wonder why you have myImageView as a member variable, not in view holder. In this case, myImageView will be changed whenever you populate(onBindViewHolder is called) new cell. @Jay

Comment: I tried this : getImgUrl = null;
        Picasso.with(context).load(getImgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).fit().into(myImageView); i placed it befoire try catch block, didnt work. You're right I will test again with ImageView in viewholder..

Comment: Problem now is that I've put imageview in MyViewHolder class, in my onBindViewHolder method, it doesn't know anymore myImageView.. @crowjdh by the way what does R.drawable.user_placeholder would refer to in my case ?

Comment: I tried your solution with using placeholder with leaving myImageView as member (I could execute the code) but same result : pictures still shifting. Otherwise still have same problem with variable myImageView, in my previous comment

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a single ImageView in member variable and also in every MyViewHolders. Please clarify your situation. What I assume is that you're trying to display image in every cell and at the same time, trying to display a single representative image for your collection. @Jay

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm doing, I just changed my listview to a recyclerview, so as my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

***Instead of try and catch provide if and else***

```
       if (yourList.profileImage != null) { 
  Picasso.with(context).load(list.getProfilePicture()).into(holder.profilePictureImageView);
        }
        else {   
    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profilePictureImageView);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me -

```
holder.imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
holder.imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
// Now set your image in imageView
```